# Extracting contours from mesh layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, vector, contour, mesh

I am writing a C++ application that loads a NetCDF file as a mesh layer.  I am attempting to utilize the QgsMeshContours class to export line geometries to be appended to a memory vector layer.  Despite my code telling me that the mesh layer I load is valid, the geometries being returned to me are empty.  I can also confirm that the values I want to contour are within the minimum and maximum values as expressed in the dataset metadata provider.  Am I calling the class correctly or is there a better way to achieve this (preferably without having to do any more GeoTiff file conversions and running a gdal_contour subprocess; that was the old way I did it).  Here's the relevant part of the code (without the steps to add everything to the Qgsproject/canvas):

```
QgsMeshLayer *mesh = new QgsMeshLayer("/path/to/file.nc","MyData","mdal");
QString contour = "MSLP";
QString destPrj = "+proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::fromProj(destPrj);

if ( mesh->isValid() )
{
     mesh->setCrs(crs);
     QgsMeshRendererSettings rens = mesh->rendererSettings();

     for ( int &i: mesh->datasetGroupsIndexes() )
     {
         QgsMeshDatasetIndex did = i;
         QgsMeshDatasetGroupMetadata gmd = mesh->datasetGroupMetadata(did);
         QString vname = gmd.name();

         if ( vname == contour )
         {
            rens.setActiveScalarDatasetGroup(i);
            mesh->setRendererSettings(rens);
            double cint = 2.0;
            double max = floor(gmd.maximum());
            double start = round(gmd.minimum())-cint;
            QgsVectorLayer *vec = new QgsVectorLayer("Linestring?crs=EPSG:4326",vname,"memory");
            QgsMeshContours contours(mesh);

            if ( vec->isValid() )
            {
                 vec->startEditing();
                 QgsVectorDataProvider *vdp = vec->dataProvider();

                 while ( start < max )
                 {
                     QgsFeature feat;
                     start = start+cint;
                     QgsGeometry line = contours.exportLines(did,start,QgsMeshRendererScalarSettings::NeighbourAverage);

                     if ( line.isEmpty() )
                     {
                         cout << "Empty geometry for value " << start << endl;
                     } else if ( line.isNull() )
                     {
                         cout << "Null geometry for value " << start << endl;
                     } else
                     {
                         feat.setGeometry(line);
                         QgsAttributes attrs;
                         QVariant att = QVariant(start);
                         attrs.append(att);
                         feat.setAttributes(attrs);
                         QList<QgsField> field;
                         field.append(QgsField(vname,QVariant::Double));
                         vdp->addAttributes((field));
                         vdp->addFeature(feat);
                     }

                     vec->commitChanges();
                }
            }
        }      
    }
}
```